# Ruby regular expression non capture group

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to grab id number from the string, say

```
id/number/2000GXZ2/ref=sr
```

using

```
(?:id\/number\/)([a-zA-Z0-9]{8})
```

for some reason non capture group is not worked, giving me:

```
id/number/2000GXZ2
```

Comment: How are you getting the result? You need to get the first captured group

Comment: The purpose of a non-capturing group is to group things without generating a capture, but not to remove the matched substring from the global match.

Comment: It is working if you properly fetch http://rubular.com/r/6NcnBGTEwy

Comment: A regex does not do anything by itself. How are you using the regex? Splitting the string with it? Substituting some parts of the string with it?

Comment: What exactly do you need to get of this: `id/number/2000GXZ2/ref=sr`? (which part)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As mentioned by others, non-capturing groups still count towards the overall match. If you don't want that part in your match use a lookbehind.
[Rubular example](http://rubular.com/r/kY1Dib5AYv)

```
(?<=id\/number\/)([a-zA-Z0-9]{8})
```

> (?<=pat) - Positive lookbehind assertion: ensures that the preceding characters match pat, but doesn't include those characters in the matched text

[Ruby Doc Regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Regexp.html)

Also, the capture group around the id number is unnecessary in this case.

Answer (score 5):

You have:

```
str = "id/number/2000GXZ2/ref=sr"

r = /
    (?:id\/number\/) # match string in a non-capture group
    ([a-zA-Z0-9]{8}) # match character in character class 8 times, in capture group 1
    /x               # extended/free-spacing regex definition mode
```

Then (using [String#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D)):

```
str[r]
  #=> "id/number/2000GXZ2"
```

returns the entire match, as it should, not just the contents of capture group 1. There are a few ways to remedy this. Consider first ones that do not use a capture group.

@jacob.m suggested putting the first part in a positive lookbehind (modified slightly from his code):

```
r = /
    (?<=id\/number\/) # match string in positive lookbehind
    [[:alnum:]]{8}    # match >= 1 alphameric characters
    /x

str[r]
  #=> "2000GXZ2"
```

An alternative is:

```
r = /
    id\/number\/   # match string
    \K             # forget everything matched so far
    [[:alnum:]]{8} # match 8 alphanumeric characters
    /x

str[r]
  #=> "2000GXZ2"
```

`\K` is especially useful when the match to forget is variable-length, as (in Ruby) positive lookbehinds do not work with variable-length matches.

With both of these approaches, if the part to be matched contains only numbers and capital letters, you may want to use `[A-Z0-9]+` instead of `[[:alnum:]]` (though the latter includes Unicode letters, not just those from the English alphabet). In fact, if all the entries have the form of your example, you might be able to use:

```
r = /
    \d          # match a digit
    [A-Z0-9]{7} # match >= 0 capital letters or digits
    /x

str[r]
  #=> "2000GXZ2"
```

The other line of approach is to keep your capture group. One simple way is:

```
r = /
    id\/number\/     # match string
    ([[:alnum:]]{8}) # match >= 1 alphameric characters in capture group 1
    /x

str =~ r
str[r, 1] #=> "2000GXZ2"
```

Alternatively, you could use [String#sub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-sub) to replace the entire string with the contents of the capture group:

```
r = /
    id\/number\/     # match string
    ([[:alnum:]]{8}) # match >= 1 alphameric characters in capture group 1
    .*               # match the remainder of the string
    /x

str.sub(r, '\1')  #=> "2000GXZ2"
str.sub(r, "\\1") #=> "2000GXZ2" 
str.sub(r) { $1 } #=> "2000GXZ2"
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for such thoroughful answer. Much apreciate it !

Answer (score 0):

This is Ruby `Regexp` *expected* match consistency evilness. Some `Regexp`-style methods will return the global-match while others will return specified matches.

In this case, one method we can use to get the behavior you're looking for is [`scan`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan).

I don't think anyone here actually mentions how to get your `Regexp` working as *you* originally intended, which was to get the capture-only match. To do that, you would use the `scan` method like so with your original pattern:

**test_me.rb**

```
test_string="id/number/2000GXZ2/ref=sr"
result = test_string.scan(/(?:id\/number\/)([a-zA-Z0-9]{8})/)
puts result
```

> ```
> 2000GXZ2
> ```

That said, replacing `(?:)` with `(?<=)` for non-capture groups for look-behinds will benefit you both when you use `scan` as well as other parts of ruby that use `Regexp`s.